# Why do we bias the exponent of a floating-point number?

Tags: floating-point, ieee-754, exponent

I'm trying to wrap my head around this floating point representation of binary numbers, but I couldn't find, no matter where I looked, a good answer to the question.

Why is the exponent biased?

What's wrong with the good old reliable two's complement method?

I tried to look at the Wikipedia's article regarding the topic, but all it says is: "the usual representation for signed values, would make comparison harder."

Comment: That same article says, two sentences later, "By arranging the fields so that the sign bit is in the most significant bit position, the biased exponent in the middle, then the mantissa in the least significant bits, the resulting value will be ordered properly, whether it's interpreted as a floating point or integer value. This allows high speed comparisons of floating point numbers using fixed point hardware." Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612775/why-ieee-floating-point-number-calculate-exponent-using-a-biased-form

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The IEEE 754 encodings have a convenient property that an order comparison can be performed between two positive non-NaN numbers by simply comparing the corresponding bit strings lexicographically, or equivalently, by interpreting those bit strings as unsigned integers and comparing those integers.  This works across the entire floating-point range from +0.0 to +Infinity (and then it's a simple matter to extend the comparison to take sign into account). Thus for example in IEEE 754 binary 64 format, `1.1` is encoded as the bit string (msb first)

```
0011111111110001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011010
```

while `0.01` is encoded as the bit string

```
0011111110000100011110101110000101000111101011100001010001111011
```

which occurs lexicographically before the bit string for `1.1`.

For this to work, numbers with smaller exponents need to compare before numbers with larger exponents.  A biased exponent makes that work, while an exponent represented in two's complement would make the comparison more involved.  I believe this is what the Wikipedia comment applies to.

Another observation is that with the chosen encoding, the floating-point number `+0.0` is encoded as a bit string consisting entirely of zeros.

Comment: if you have one's complement integer hardware the whole range of numbers sorts correctly

Comment: Or, with twos compliment 64-bit x and y, you can xor a signed and unsigned comparison to correctly handle signs: `((uint64_t)x > (uint64_t)y) ^ ((int64_t)x < (int64_t)y)` to test x greater-than y and `((uint64_t)x <= (uint64_t)y) ^ ((int64_t)x > (int64_t)y)` to test x less-than-or-equal y. This works for infinity but fails in two cases: (1.) negative zero equals positive zero and (2.) any operation against NaN is false, infamously `NaN != NaN` is true

Answer (score 4):

I do not recall the specifics, but there was some desire for the highest exponent to be slightly farther from zero than the least normal exponent. This increases the number of values *x* for which both *x* and its reciprocal are approximately representable. For example, with IEEE-754 64-bit binary floating-point, the normal exponent range is -1022 to 1023. This makes the largest finite representable value just under 2<sup>1024</sup>, so the interval for which *x* and its reciprocal are both approximately representable is almost 2<sup>-1024</sup> to almost 2<sup>1024</sup>. (Numbers at the very low end of this interval are subnormal, so some precision is being lost, but they are still representable.)

With a two’s complement representation, the exponent values would range from -1024 to 1023, and we have to reserve two of them to handle zeros, subnormals, infinities, and NaNs. That leaves a range of -1023 to 1022. With this, the interval for *x* such that both *x* and its reciprocal are approximately representable is almost 2<sup>-1023</sup> to 2<sup>1023</sup>. Thus, the biased arrangement provides a greater useful range of values.

Comment: This answer seems to me to be more about the choice of which values to represent than about the bit encoding.  It would still have been possible to use two's complement instead of a biased exponent for the exponent field (reserving the bit patterns `10000000000` and `10000000001` for representations of infinities, nans, zeros and subnormals), without affecting the set of representable values.

Comment: @MarkDickinson: Yes, the goal is to choose which values to represent. And the bias gives you that choice. The bias is an adjustable parameter; you can set it to the value that gives the desired set of represented values. That is why it is preferable to two’s complement, which fixes the encoded exponent values. (Playing with which values to reserve is a kludge, breaks the property that all-bits-zero represents zero, and breaks the ordering property you note in your answer.)

Answer (score 2):

[image]

I believe this picture will help you to understand what Mark Dickinson said `simply comparing the corresponding bit strings lexicographically, or equivalently, by interpreting those bit strings as unsigned integers and comparing those integers.`

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Offset_binary