# Memory representation of the exponent part of floating point numbers?

Tags: floating-point

The memory representation of floating-point number involves expressing the number in scientific notation in the binary number system. I have three questions related to how the exponent part is represented in memory.

1. Why we bias the exponent?
2. What is the problem if we use 2’s complement to represent negative exponents instead of a bias?
3. Why do we use 127 as the bias?

I present my understanding below to pin point where I am getting stuck.

**Why we bias the exponent: Is My Understanding correct?**
If exponents in the floating-point numbers are represented as it is, for example, if the exponent is -5 and we represent this numbers directly, then it leads to two problems:

1. The numbers 0 (0.0 x 20) and 1 (1.0 x 20) have same representations
2. Also, negative exponents are difficult to represent in the hardware specially if we are using the sign-magnitude notation where one bit is reserved for the sign

The second problem can be partially solved using the 2’s complement representation – but even then, we do not have a way to differentiate between the representation of 0 and 1. Reason – the two complements of zero is still zero. Therefore, I understand zero has been made a special case and biasing the exponent helps turn the negative exponents positive and also helps us represent 1.

**Question: Is the above understanding, correct?**

***What is the problem if we use 2’s complement to represent negative exponents instead of a bias?***

One obvious problem that comes to my mind is of course that 2’s complement still cannot differentiate between the representations of 0 and 1. But the answer in this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19864749/why-do-we-bias-the-exponent-of-a-floating-point-number) points out the following:

> The IEEE 754 encodings have a convenient property that an order
> comparison can be performed between two positive non-NaN numbers by
> simply comparing the corresponding bit strings lexicographically, or
> equivalently, by interpreting those bit strings as unsigned integers
> and comparing those integers.

I understand that biasing the exponent by 127 helps us deal only with unsigned integers. But what is the meaning of “comparing the corresponding bit strings lexicographically, or equivalently”?? A user has also provided a table below – but I am not still understanding it. Can anyone please elaborate on this?

Suppose I have two numbers: 1.0 x 2-7 and 1.0 x 2-8 then the memory representation of -7 (120: 01111000) and -8 (121: 01111001). I have represented them in the following manner with labels.

[image: bitwise comparison]

Now if we are comparing the corresponding bit strings does it mean that we are comparing the zero (from the 120 row) and one (from the row 121) under label H for example? **Is this correct understanding? And if this is correct……what do we gain out of it? If this is not correct what we are doing then what exactly does the statement mean?**

Also, it is mentioned in the same answer that 0.1 appears lexicographically before 1.1. What does this mean? The post mentions the binary equivalent of both 0.1 and 1.1…**for a lexicographic comparison, should I look at any particular bit?**

And finally, the answer also mentions

> For this to work, numbers with smaller exponents need to compare
> before numbers with larger exponents. A biased exponent makes that
> work, while an exponent represented in two's complement would make the
> comparison more involved

Can someone pls explain this remark also…I am not finding it to be self-explanatory.

***Why do we bias it by 127?***

Is there any reason to choose 127? I mean a random number like 543 works fine!! Also, I request you to let me know if this choice of 127 is a result of a lot of complicated mathematics. In that case pls guide me if I should just accept it and move on?

Comment: Just using a sign bit makes the hardware implementation more difficult. The question should be why not to use the usual unsigned integer format. It may also depend on the interpretation of the mantissa, if it is `1.m` or `0.1m`.

Comment: @Sougata What exponent would you use for 0.0 in your suggested encoding?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I get your point. Shall come back with a more pointed question in a couple of days time.