# Why can't we store exponent of IEEE floating point number without adding bias or converting it to 2's or 1's complement?

Tags: floating-point, computer-science, cpu-architecture, ieee-754

Why do we have to add bias or convert an exponent of IEEE floating point number in its 2's or 1's complement form ??
why can't we store it like this in single precision :

1.1 * 2^0 => 0 00000000 10000000000000000000000

instead of this:

1.1 * 2^ (0 + 127) => 0 01111111 10000000000000000000000

thanks

Comment: I think you'll find a good answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612775/why-ieee-floating-point-number-calculate-exponent-using-a-biased-form?rq=1)

Comment: My question is different you can see its different

Comment: How would you represent negative exponents?

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan i would represent it in 1's or 2's complement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bias format for the exponent let you do this nice trick:

Given a floating point *f*, denote with <*f*> its binary representation.
Denote with + the integer addition.

Then

```
<f> + 1 = nextafter(f)
```

towards the infinity of the same sign of *f*.

This is true as long as the sum doesn't affect the sign bit.

Comment: It also simplifies comparisons in hardware. Ignoring NaNs, the order of magnitude of the floats matches the unsigned binary order of the bit patterns with the sign bit chopped off.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan Very good point!